# How to accumulate drag offset without global variable using rxjs

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I need to implement the background offset functionality using mouse drag, the challenging part compared to normal drag implementation is to keep the total offset accumulated by each drag behavior
Here is the solution I figured out

```
let xOffset = 0 //not able to fit this state into Observable stream
const drag$ =
    mousedown$
        .switchMap(({ point: mousedown }) => {
            return mousemove$
                .map(({ point: mousemove }) => mousemove[0] - mousedown[0])
                .do((deltaX) => {
                    chart.transform({ x: deltaX + xOffset })
                })
                .takeUntil(mouseup$)
                .takeLast(1)
        })
        .scan((x, y) => x + y)
        .do(x => xOffset = x)
```

The problem is that I took advatage of a global variable to keep track of the total offset which is againt the philosophy of rxjs, any way to achieve this without global?

Comment: Just move the `scan` so that it accumulates the deltas *before* you set the transform.

Comment: @cartant This should be the correct direction but very hard to achieve

Comment: @cartant because `scan` should only be invoked when the drag complete, i.e. `mouseup` rather that duing the drag i.e. `mousemove`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the solution

```
const dragBG$ = mousedown$
    .switchMapTo(mousemove$
        .pairwise()
        .map(([[x1], [x2]]) => x2 - x1)
        .takeUntil(mouseup$)
    )
    .scan((x, y) => x + y)
    .do((x) => {
        chart.transform({ x })
    })
```

The key is not to compare mousedown and mousemove. By doing that, the value can never be accumulated. Rather, calculated the delta of two mousemove